# Rotation of eigenvectors of a time-dependent tensor

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tensors

I have a symmetric, real tensor in ${\mathbb R}^3  $ where the components are continuous functions of time:
$${\mathbf D} = \left( 
\begin{matrix}
d_{1,1}(t) & d_{1,2}(t) & d_{1,3}(t) \\
d_{1,2}(t) & d_{2,2}(t) & d_{2,3}(t) \\
d_{1,3}(t) & d_{2,3}(t) & d_{3,3}(t)
\end{matrix}
\right) $$

Because of it symmetry, the tensor will have three eigenvalues and
corresponding eigenvectors.

The eigenvectors will be (barrind degenerate cases) perpendicular to each
other, and also funcitons of time - they will rotate in space.

I want to determine this rotation (axis of rotation and angular velocity) as a function of time.

Of course, I can determine the eigenvectors using the usual numerical
methods at $t$ and $t + \Delta t$, solve for the components of the transformation matrix and divide by the time step (in effect performing a numerical dfferentiation), but this seems rather cumbersome.

Is there another, more elegant way?

Comment: Can you solve general case for the eigenvectors of the time dependent matrix?

Comment: [I hit "Enter" too soon on my previous comment.] Well, yes, using a "brute force" algorithm - using the trigonometric soluiton for the eigenvaues (since I know that all three will be real) and calculating the eigenvectors analytically (by imposing another constraint such as $e1+e2+e3 = 1$ to make the system determined, at least for the non-degenerate case.  Carrying through all the time derivatives of my vector can be done, of course (this is almost always possible), but I expect hundreds of pages of Maple output, at least.